# Mac mini power cord

Tags: mac-mini

I somehow misplaced the power cord for my mac mini. It's the model from last year, so the one before the currently being sold model.

Where can I get a replacement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually a good idea to check on the [manufacturer's page](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MA407LL/A) first.

Comment: I saw that, but it's 49 bucks, which is ridonculous.